# Can WaitForMultipleObjects or WaitForSingleObject be used with asynchronous ReadFile()?

Tags: c, asynchronous, io

I am trying to use WaitForMultipleObjects() to wait for multiple asynchronous ReadFile() completion, however it always return immediately and no byte has been read. On the other hand, GetOverlappedResult() is always successful. I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

I'm testing this with just one asynchornous ReadFile() in this block of code below.

```
events = (HANDLE *)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE));
buffer = (BYTE*)malloc(BufferSize*sizeof(BYTE));
memset(buffer, 0, BufferSize*sizeof(BYTE));
hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
if (!hEvent){
    printf("can't create event\n");
    return 0;
}

memset(&testOv, 0, sizeof(testOv));
testOv.hEvent = hEvent; //event to use with waitformultipleobject()
testFile = CreateFile(SrcDst[0][0], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE==testFile) 
{
printf("Unable to open file %s.  Error=%d\n",SrcDst[0][0], GetLastError());
return 0;
}

events[0] = testOv.hEvent; 

RF = ReadFile(testFile, buffer, 25, &byteRead, &testOv);

//WaitForMultipleObjects(1, events, TRUE, INFINITE); return before any byte is read
//WaitForSingleObject(testFile, INFINITE); waiting indefinitely

GetOverlappedResult(testFile, &testOv, &byteRead, TRUE);

for (i = 0; i < byteRead; i++){
    printf("%c", (char)buffer[i]);
}

printf("byteRead: %d\n", byteRead);
printf("error: %d\n", GetLastError());
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: I see no problem. ReadFile() returns. WaitForMultipleObjects returns a 0, indicating the events are all signaled. GetOverlappedResult() (with FALSE as last param) returns immediately. All the bytes were read.  Were you thinking you didn't have to call GetOverlappedResult() if you used WaitForMultipleObjects()?  Otherwise, you'll have to clarify. I see the bytes being read fine with either method...